# Spreadsheetlight Pie-chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, model-view-controller

How do i display percentage on my pie chart using spreadsheetlight?

This is my current code

```
        double fChartHeight = 15.0;
        double fChartWidth = 7.5;

        SLChart chart;

        chart = sl.CreateChart("N1", "R2");
        chart.SetChartType(SLPieChartType.Pie);
        chart.SetChartPosition(piechartRow, 0, piechartRow + fChartHeight, fChartWidth);
        chart.Title.Shadow.SetPreset(SpreadsheetLight.Drawing.SLShadowPresetValues.PerspectiveDiagonalUpperLeft);              
        sl.InsertChart(chart);

        sl.SaveAs(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but hope this gets you in the right direction.

```
    double fChartHeight = 15.0;
    double fChartWidth = 7.5;

    SLChart chart;

    chart = sl.CreateChart("N1", "R2");
    chart.SetChartType(SLPieChartType.Pie);
    chart.SetChartPosition(piechartRow, 0, piechartRow + fChartHeight, fChartWidth);
    chart.Title.Shadow.SetPreset(SpreadsheetLight.Drawing.SLShadowPresetValues.PerspectiveDiagonalUpperLeft);

    SLGroupDataLabelOptions grplabels = chart.CreateGroupDataLabelOptions();
    grplabels.ShowPercentage = true;
    grplabels.ShowValue = false;
    chart.SetGroupDataLabelOptions(grplabels);

    sl.InsertChart(chart);

    sl.SaveAs(path);
```

If you want to tweak individual data labels, then use the SLDataLabelOptions class. Basically, imagine how you'd do it in Excel. In fact, do make a pie chart in Excel. Format the pie chart to what you want it to look. Replicate the steps you did in Excel with SpreadsheetLight.